# Filling a non-convex path in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, path-clipping

I am trying to fill a path consisting of two semicircles, and I only want the area between them to be filled. The following code doesn't work correctly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[active,pdftex,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment[]{tikzpicture}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
 \filldraw[yellow,draw=black] (0em,0em) arc[radius=1em, start angle=180, end angle=0]
   (2em,0em) --  (2em,-1em) arc[radius=1em, start angle=0, end angle=180]
   (0em,-1em) -- (0em,0em);
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

What I get is this:

[image: Incorrect filling]

Also, if I use the path for clipping, the same incorrect filled area is used. Can someone figure out how to fill the area inside the drawn semicircles (non-convex area) only?

Comment: (+1) for completing your code even though you already had answers. That makes your question more useful to future readers.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to specify a *continuous* path for the fill for this to work neatly. So don't specify coordinates which you've already drawn to as that introduces a discontinuity:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\filldraw[yellow,draw=black]
  (0em,0em)
    arc[radius=1em, start angle=180, end angle=0]
    --  (2em,-1em)
    arc[radius=1em, start angle=0, end angle=180]
    -- (0em,0em);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: yellow]

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=4]{standalone}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \filldraw[yellow,draw=black] (0,0) arc[radius=1em, start angle=0, end angle=180]
  --  ++(0em,-1em) arc[radius=1em, start angle=180, end angle=0]
  -- ++(0em,1em) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the correct answer, but I selected cfr's solution since it came with an explanation.